# Autohotkey: Paste/write a simple line of text with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: autohotkey

This is a super simple thing I am trying to get my head around

I want to use something like WINKEY + ALT + C to paste ** - words** so that I can sign-off my posts or whatever using the three-key combo

Comment: What is your question? Show us what you've tried!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want, maybe something like this?

Press WINKEY + ALT + C to paste the clipboard contents:

```
#!c::
  SendInput, ^v
Return
```

Press WINKEY + ALT + C to paste "Some random text"

```
#!c::
  SendInput, Some random text
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Sendinput which will type each characters you can use a clipboard paste approach. See for example https://github.com/tdalon/ahk/blob/59a8ab2a8fd497b4a5b5a85e73e32ff95d5d4425/Lib/Clip.ahk

```
Clip_Paste(sText,restore := True) {
; Syntax: Clip_Paste(sText,restore := True)
If (restore)
    ClipBackup:= ClipboardAll
Clipboard := sText
WinClip.Paste()
If (restore) 
    Clip_Restore(ClipBackup)
} ; eofun

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Clip_Restore(ClipBackup) {
Clip_Wait() ; in order not to overwrite running clipboard action like pasting
Clipboard:= ClipBackup
} ;eofun
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Clip_Wait(){
Sleep, 150
while DllCall("user32\GetOpenClipboardWindow", "Ptr")
    Sleep, -1
} ; eofun
```